# Make PDF Editable

Tags: pdf, editing

Is there any way to make a PDF file editable?  I want to be able to type in the information manually.  I've been working on making a template in Word to try to accomplish the same type of result, but I can't get it to match what I need.  The lines don't match up with the recipe cards (pre printed) that I'm trying to populate.

Comment: I use Adobe Acrobat pro DC. It uses OCR technology to recognize the characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking at multiple PDF editors and only one was capable of modifying and creating form templates. It is called [Foxit Phantom PDF](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-editor/). Unfortunately this product is **not free, but it does have a free trial period of 14 days** (without credit-card). Hopefully, you will not need to use it again after this period of time. I have used this editor before, for a short period, and it worked well for what I had to do. Using the product it seemed there were many tools to modify the document, so if it is for just some basic modification this should work okay for you especially if it were a one time thing. It is very advanced in my opinion.

[image: Evidence of Form modification and capability]

Once opened you can create or modify any PDF document, although only during the Trial period. If your goal is to make forms it is accessible in the Form tab at the top. The program should be likable and easy to use as it is laid out in a similar fashion as Microsoft Office Word, since you seem familiar with it.

To install the free trial from the link I gave: Choose "Free Trial Download" underneath "PhantomPDF Standard". It should redirect you and give you a popup to fill out some personal info explaining it. If this is for personal use put in "Personal" in the Company text-field. Once done filling out all the required fields continue and the download should start. Open the download, choose Typical (or if you want Custom) and install it.

[Here is the software manual](http://cdn01.foxitsoftware.com/pub/foxit/manual/phantom/en_us/FoxitPhantomPDF831_Manual.pdf) if you need assistance using the product.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to create in PDF are called `Forms` and you need to use Acrobat version of Adobe PDF.
A PDF reader would not allow you to create Forms. 
Just in case if you do not have an Acrobat version installed in your computer, you could get this done [online](https://www.jotform.com/fillable-pdf-form-creator/)